# Is there any benefit in using <link rel="preload"> or <link rel="preconnect"> for resources on the same domain as the original page?

Tags: optimization, preload, preconnect

I've been reading up on performance benefits of using  and  to help fetch critical resources but one thing I can't quite figure out is whether these techniques still offer benefit when the resource is located on the same domain as the page that's requesting them.

E.g. I'm optimizing a page at abc.com Should I add a `<link rel="preconnect" href="abc.com">` or `<link rel="preload" as="script" href="abc.com/main.js">` to my markup? Or will it not have any effect since the current page is on the same domain as the link href values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preconnect` will have no effect (you are already connected to the domain).

`preload` will have an effect (causing resource to be fetched immediately, without waiting to discover where in the page is it used).